# Let me choose permalinks

Tags: permalinks, pages, duplicates

I need to pick a permalink called 'mysite.com/1418', but wordpress keeps adding '-2' to the permalink. Normally this means i already have a page called the same that is in the trash or something. But that doesn't seem the case here. I tried resetting the permalinks in the settings this also doesn't help.

How can i use numbers as page name permalink, without wordpress adding the '-2' to to permalink.

Answer (score 0):

That should only happen if, as you say, there is a post with the same unique permalink. Any in the trash will still have the same effect.